# How to get the newly created system generated Id after EF Add request

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My `Session` class looks like this:

```
public class Session
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string? SessionDetails { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime  { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public int Valid { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to create a POST that will create an instance of session with `StartTime` as system date (EF: Add). After session is over I would call the EF : Update call to store the EndTime.

Question: is there any way to get the system generated `Id` in response when I add the instance? That way I can keep the `Id` and then use it to update.

Comment: You will get it automatically after SaveChanges() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Id` is database generated then EF Core automatically will update it after `SaveChanges` call:

```
Session session = new ...;
_dbContext.Sessions.Add(session);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
Console.WriteLine(session.Id); // will print generated by db value
```